# how to transition properly in react and d3 (live line chart)

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, svg

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.createBarChart()
    window.setInterval(()=>{
        this.props.data.push(Math.random()*500)
        this.createBarChart()
        this.props.data.shift()
    },500)
}

createBarChart(){
    const delay = transition().duration(500)
    const node = this.svgNode.current
    const dataMax = max(this.props.data)
    const yScale = scaleLinear()
        .domain([0,dataMax])
        .range([0,500])

    const xScale = scaleBand()
        .range([0,500])
        .domain(this.props.data)

    let valueline = line()
        .x((d)=>xScale(d))
        .y(d=>500-yScale(d))
        .curve(curveCardinal)

    select(node)
        .append('path')
        .datum(this.props.data)
        .attr('stroke', 'steelblue')
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr('d', valueline)
        .attr('transform', null)
        .transition(delay)
        .attr('transform', `translate(${+xScale(-1)})`)
}

render(){
    return (
        <svg width={500} height={500} ref={this.svgNode}></svg>
    )
}
```

I know you're not supposed to mutate props, i'll fix that later and deal with everything in the local state, but the problem I want to fix is for the line graph to transition properly like a live time series chart.

What i'm getting right now with this code, is that every 500ms it'll draw the right line chart on top of the previous draw, instead of moving to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you **add** a new path at each tick (`.append(path)`).

What you need to do is animate the path already in the graph. And give the path an `id` or `class` because you will have more then 1 `path` in the graph (the axis also contain paths)

On the `tick` (setInterval) call a different function.

Is the `;` key on your keyboard broken?

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.createBarChart();
}

createBarChart(){
    const delay = transition().duration(500);
    const node = this.svgNode.current;
    const dataMax = max(this.props.data);
    const yScale = scaleLinear()
        .domain([0,dataMax])
        .range([500,0]);

    this.props.xScale = scaleBand()
        .range([0,500])
        .domain(this.props.data);

    this.props.valueline = line()
        .x(d=>xScale(d))
        .y(d=>yScale(d))
        .curve(curveCardinal);

    select(node)
        .append('path')
        .attr("class", "line")
        .datum(this.props.data)
        .attr('stroke', 'steelblue')
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .ease(d3.easeLinear) // you don't want cubic interpolation
            .on("start", this.updateBarChart.bind(this));
}

updateBarChart() {

    this.props.data.push(Math.random()*500);

    // this is not the path but the Component
    let line = select(this.svgNode.current).select(".line")
        .attr('d', this.props.valueline)
        .attr('transform', null);
    d3.active(line.node())
        .attr('transform', `translate(${+this.props.xScale(-1)})`)
      .transition()
        .on("start", tick);

    this.props.data.shift();
}

render(){
    return (
        <svg width={500} height={500} ref={this.svgNode}></svg>
    )
}
```